# International connection procedure at Montreal airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, canada, layovers, montreal

I am flying from USA to China via Montreal Trudeau airport on Air Canada. In Toronto, there is a special corridor to bypass customs and security (CATSA), with only a cursory immigration check. Does Montreal have the same? My connection time is only 75 minutes so I am worried about the feasibility of making the connection.

Comment: Do you have a Canadian visa?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that it's a single booking all the way to China and Air Canada will automatically transfer your luggage. In that case, you will go through a border control primary inspection and directed to the international departures area. This is the standard procedure for a [USA - International Connection](http://www.admtl.com/en/guide/connecting-flights) at Montreal Airport.

The good thing about Montreal airport is that they provide an 'almost' real-time estimate of the duration it might take through checkpoints. [Here](http://www.admtl.com/en/guide/estimated-wait-time), have a look.

I would recommend that you get the app [YULi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.underlabs.adm&hl=en) on your phone. It's a very useful app and will give you a personalized map and the estimated time it will take to complete your connection on your day of travel.

In short, 75 minutes would be enough for a connection and you may also have time to browse some duty-free too.

On the other hand, if the airline does not automatically transfer your luggage then you will need to follow the standard international arrivals and international departures procedure which would take more time.

Comment: As both a Montrealer frequent flier and a software developer (as are you), I'll add that I'm very wary of the YULi app and never installed it. It seems unnecessarily invasive (permissions) and has horrible ratings. The suggestion of admtl time estimated wait time board is great though.